# Chatbox not working c#,Visual Studio ,Winforms,Bunifu UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chat, bunifu

I have a problem that i dont understand at all , i need your help...
I am working in a chat , i will do it with sockets , but the problem isnot this ,
I created a control user to my chat box... and another to my bubbles i am trying to use this control users from my main form

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chatbox a = new bunifchat.chatbox();
            
            a.send2message("ABC");

        }
```

chatbox is the name of my controlUser and i am trying to use his method send2message, i know that it works but not correctly.

```
public void send2message(String message)
        {
            bubble bbl = new bunifchat.bubble(message);
            bbl.Location = bubble1.Location; bbl.Left += 100; //add intent
            bbl.Size = bubble1.Size;
            bbl.Anchor = bubble1.Anchor;
            bbl.Top = bbl_old.Bottom + 20;
            panel2.Controls.Add(bbl);
            
            //bottom.Top = bbl.Bottom + 50;

            bbl_old = bbl;  //safe the last added object
            
        }
```

this method receive the string and create the bubble entering to other controlUser, it works when i run it from the ControlUser Chatbox with the next code:

```
private void buttonx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
            String respuesta = txtbox.Text;
            sendmessage("hola mundo");
            send2message(respuesta);
            panel2.VerticalScroll.Value = panel2.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
        }
```

but if i run it from my main form , nothing happens,the code of my bubble is this:

```
public bubble(String message)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            label1.Text = message;
            Setheight();

        }
```

if i am not explicit, please ask , i need help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryimi.png)

when i press the button green , it create more bubbles(blue rectangules) , but i want to send the content from my main form and not from my chat box.

Answer (score 0):

> i will do it with sockets

Does that mean you use a socket to receive data on a different thread than the UI-thread?
If so, you need to check, if oyu need to invoke before accessing / creating a new object.

```
private bool AddMessage(string msg)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
            return (bool)this.Invoke((Func<string,bool>)AddMessage, msg);
    
    //DO stuff here
    send2message(msg);

    return false;
}
```